# youtube-ios-player-helper cannot open video in Youtube app

Tags: ios, youtube, helper

We use youtube-ios-player-helper to play youtube video.
But we found there is no way to open video in Youtube app or safari.
We try to long press the Youtube icon, then it showed an action sheet.
[image]
[image]

We pressed the open button, but nothing happened.
Anyone knows how to open video in Youtube app or safari?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it's my bad.
I've commented the line "[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];" in function handleHttpNavigationToUrl() before to solve ad issue.